# Decreasing number of admin-ajax requests - WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a client that have to optimize for SEO and pagespeed. The website is WordPress using classified ads theme - AdForest. Which the problems are coming from. I have tried anything from turning off all plugins  to plugins etc., none worked, he does not want to pay for support extension. So I have a problem. The theme is doing HIGH CPU overload and we changed from hosting to VPS, which did not solved the problem.

I see that if someone is on the main page, just load it and do nothing, leave it opened for hour and a half it will load more than 5 000 requests from admin-ajax most of them are coming from custm.js file in the theme, the lines that I sow in Chrome console are usually important, but I think endless loading of requests is not right.

It's doing it every second. Imagine what happens if there are 15 users at one time.... And this is the most expensive VPS package with 8 GHZ processor many CPU time 8 Gb RAM etc.

Anyway. I WANT to reduce the requests for example: 100 requests per hour per user or something like that. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply limit the execution frequency. You can do this by using a plugin called [Heartbeat Control.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/)

Once the plugin is installed then go to Settings -> Heartbeat Control Settings and from the Heartbeat Behavior drop-down choose Modify Heartbeat. If you are using the WP Rocket caching plugin then it's possible to control heartbeat from the [WP Rocket settings](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1119-control-wordpress-heartbeat-api).

Alternatively, you can choose the option Disable Heartbeat. This should completely disable this functionality and it will no longer add to the executions number and CPU time used on your server. Please note disabling heartbeat can in some cases stop some plugin functionality from working.

To disable heartbeat edit the functions.php file of your child theme and paste the snippet below right after the opening

```
add_action( 'init', 'stop_heartbeat', 1 );
function stop_heartbeat() {
wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
}
```

Comment: I already did this. And weird or not, the problem was not solved. It still do it, and If you check the website quickmarket .co .uk you will see in browser Console tab Network that the querries are runing nonstop